# Sony Vaio SVF1521C5E sound problem with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, laptop, vaio, sony

I have a problem on my Sony Vaio Fit 15 E (SVF1521C5E) running Ubuntu 12.04.02 x64.
In particular I can't hear any sound from my speakers.
I have no problem to listen with the headphones.

My hardware is the following:

```
$ lspci -nn|egrep 'ultimedia|udio|sound|AC97|ac97|EMU'
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller    (rev 04)

$ aplay -l
**** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0


$ cat /proc/asound/car*/co* |  grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ID 233
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem upgrading my ALSA drivers:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Simple and fast. Now the sound works fine!

P.S. For more informations you can see this question:

[Sony Vaio Fit with Ubuntu 12.04, sound missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321804/sony-vaio-fit-with-ubuntu-12-04-sound-missing)