# Sony Vaio Fit with Ubuntu 12.04, sound missing

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, vaio

The speakers in my Sony Vaio Fit SVF15A1C5E don't work, while headphones do.

`lspci -nn|egrep 'ultimedia|udio|sound|AC97|ac97|EMU'`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
```

`aplay -l`:

```
\**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices \****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`cat /proc/asound/car*/co* |  grep Codec`:

```
Codec: Realtek ID 233
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMIow to proceed
```

Adding

```
options snd-hda-intel enable=1 index=0 model=basic
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` doesn't help.

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (headphones working fine, but no audio from internal speakers) with the same audio specs under Ubuntu 13.04, Linux kernel 3.8.

I updated the alsa drivers according to the instructions given in the [Ubuntu help wiki page on Alsa](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS) for my kernel version.

After installation of the new drivers (package `oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-raring-dkms`) and reboot, the sound worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As your headphones work, Linux has your sound hardware driver. Sound issues in Linux are mostly because of bad mixer status.

Install and check `alsamixer` or `pavucontrol` and check the mixer. In mixers look for any muted volumes and also test right/left sliders; sometimes some sound hardware (mostly microphones) only works when mixer is set to only left channel.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by upgrading the kernel. Which might break the Wifi driver for this model tho.