# Ubuntu 13.04/13.10 on Sony Vaio Fit 15 SVF15A1C5E

Tags: installation, 13.04, vaio, 13.10

I am planning on buying this laptop: Sony Vaio Fit 15 (SVF15A1C5E) with very high-end specs:

> Intel® CoreTM i7-3537U, 2 GHz, 39.5cm LED 1920 x 1080 +webcam, NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 735M 2 GB, 512 GB SATA Flash SSD, 12 GB 1600 MT/S DDR3L-SDRAM

I wanted to know if anybody has installed Ubuntu 13.04 (or future 13.10) on this model. I've read in another post that there might be a minor sound issue which is fixable with an update. But other than that, will I be able to just wipe out Windows, and put a clean Ubuntu install without any issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've searched, It works OK, except for configuration of the sound card:

[Sony Vaio Fit with Ubuntu 12.04, sound missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321804/sony-vaio-fit-with-ubuntu-12-04-sound-missing?rq=1)

And a major problem with the Wifi card, that its not acknowledged by Sony. The only really effective solution to that is to replace wifi card with a better one, for example:

[Intel Network 6235AN.HMWWB Centrino WiFi Card Advanced-N 6235 Dual Band Bluetooth Retail](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007QXLIWI)

[image]